# Altering Adapter data

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have a `ListActivity`.  Each item in the `ListView` contains a `RatingBar`.  When the user manipulates the `RatingBar`, I want to update the corresponding data attached to the Adapter.

Unfortunately, inside my `RatingBar` handler, I can't refer to the position variable.  I understand why.  I'm just having trouble finding a way around it.

How would I handle what I'm trying to do here?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // grab view
    View v = convertView;
    // set view layout
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_rating_ratingbubble, null);
        RatingBar r = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.rating_rating);
        if (r != null) {
            r.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromUser) {
                        // CANT REFER TO position HERE
                        m_items.get(position).setRating((int)rating);
                    }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done...

Inside the onRatingChanged handler, we first need to find the position.  I've created a small method to do this:

```
    private int getListPosition(View v) {
        View vParent = (View)v.getParent();
        if (vParent != null) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)vParent.getParent();
            if (vg != null) {
                return getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition() + vg.indexOfChild(vParent);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The rest is simple.  Take the result of this method (x) and call:

```
m_items.get(x).setRating((int)rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your code is not working giving you an error on:

```
m_items.get(position).setRating((int)rating);
```

Try doing this:

```
if (r != null) {
            final int position2 = position;
            r.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromUser) {
                        m_items.get(position2).setRating((int)rating);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This doesn't work for me.  When I debug the handler, it says position2 cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // grab view
    View v = convertView;
    // set view layout
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_rating_ratingbubble, null);
        RatingBar r = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.rating_rating);
        if (r != null) {
            r.setTag(position); // Set the position number as the tag on the view
            r.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromUser) {
                        int item_position = (int)ratingBar.getTag(); // Retrieve tag
                        m_items.get(item_position).setRating((int)rating);
                    }
                });
        }
        return v;
}
```

Although, I would probably add the `RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener` interface to another object that is instantiated once. (Even the adapter, if you wanted, although it probably doesn't belong there.)  As it is, you're creating a new listener object for each RatingBar and that's a little wasteful in the memory department.

Comment: Someone posted this solution and then deleted the solution once I posed my problem with it.  My problem is that my list can be altered by the user (ex: deleting a row).  This messes up all the indices of the rows below the deleted row.  Perhaps adding an ELSE case to that IF-statement and updating the tag would help, but obviously that only happens when the row comes into view.  There may be situations where that causes strange behavior.

Comment: I think tag is really only useful when you are using the ID of a row as it pertains to the data behind it.  Uses indexes becomes problematic.